# Hibernation Fails, Suspected Video Card Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, hibernate

Each time I attempt Hibernation, it fails. Nothing is saved, and when the computer is powered back on, it reminds me the computer did not shut down properly.

I'm almost positive it's my fault, but I'm hoping for a workaround. I am running Windows 7 on the Intel HD 620 graphics card, using this hack to get the driver working for Win 7: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w9JofZQkxI. All other functionality is perfect.

- Is there a way to verify for certain hibernation is failing because of the driver?
- If so, is there any possibility to fix it, or am I screwed without hibernation with this laptop?

Comment: Hibernation is failing NOT because of the graphics drivers, even "hacked" ones. Hibernation problems are almost always related with the drive where the the system partition resides which has either 1) insufficient free space or 2) corruption (logical and/or physical errors). **Suspension**, not hibernation, is what can be affected by improper graphics drivers or power management settings. **Which one are you actually talking about, hibernation or suspension?**

Comment: The system (boot) partition has 800+GB of free space, and it's a brand new computer. There is a 2nd partition with a 2nd installation of Windows. That has 18GB free. But I am trying to hibernate from the partition with 800GB. As for sleep mode (suspension?), it was indeed disabled until I had graphics drivers installed, so this makes sense. It works flawlessly and without issue, but hibernation fails every time.

Comment: Start by using the error correction tools for the system partition (reboot required, it'll run in the next boot). If it doesn't solve it then consider not using hibernation - I don't see the point of hibernating a modern fast PC - or using an adequate OS for your hardware, Win7 is not.

Comment: What are the error correction tools? Google shows nothing. Hibernation is fantastic! It preserves the open programs, tabs, files, notes, of which I have always have many. In low battery situations, this is a lifesaver since if the computer cannot automatically hibernate, it would result in data loss every time a low battery event occurred. As a battery ages, it becomes more and important. Windows 7 is also phenomenal. I would consider Windows 10 to be far less than adequate for anyone concerned with effectiveness or any degree of privacy since layers of obfuscation make every task difficult.

Comment: I could have said `chkdsk` but error correction is how it shows in the GUI that you can open by right-clicking a partition and choosing Properties, one of the tabs is Tools: https://www.minitool.com/images-mt/data-recovery/201801/data-error-crc-5.jpg . There are better ways to save a session and shutdown normally: https://www.pcworld.com/article/3131336/windows/how-to-have-windows-re-open-active-windows-and-programs-on-reboot.html Hibernation is not necessary. And your hardware couldn't care less about your opinions about Windows (...)

Comment: The fact is your hardware was designed for a newer OS. Windows 7 works but not as good and with several caveats, one of them you already know, the need to "hack" a driver the manufacturer doesn't support for Win7. And finally, Win7 is what is more familiar to you but it doesn't make it "better" is any way. Even the privacy issue is largely overblown, clickbait mostly. Win7 does the exact same. Someone that has to ask about correcting errors in a drive is certainly not qualified to discuss those issues anyway. Please note that I'm not defending Windows, I use it less than 1% total (99% LINUX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be no copping out today. Fixed with: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2908783/data-corruption-occurs-on-iscsi-luns-in-windows

Long live Windows 7 ;)